# How can I make an arbitrary sized html element with partially transparent borders?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following image:

[image: grass with deckle edge]

This is supposed to look like a patch of grass with rough (deckled) edges.  It's a 200x200 pixel png image, with transparency at the edges to give a natural look.

The problem is, I'm trying to design a web page where I want various elements of all different sizes to have this background, but I can't use a simple css background property, because repeating an image like this doesn't work: the transparency on the left, for instance, in plainly visible as a seam between each copy of the image.  But if I simply stretch the image to fit, it doesn't look very good either.

Is there any (cross browser) way to accomplish this?  jQuery solutions are acceptable as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A jQuery solution:

http://code.google.com/p/scale9grid/

---

`border-image` is the pure CSS solution:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-image

Unfortunately, the browser support is not yet good enough: http://caniuse.com/border-image

A generator: http://border-image.com/

Comment: It is of course possible to have it work in every browser and without JavaScript if you slice up your image and make a bunch of extra `div`s. But it's (relatively) a lot of work.

Comment: I had no idea this plugin existed. I can think of several applications for rough-edges on a DIV. Very cool.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with the CSS3 [border-image](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3a%22http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png%22,%22linkBorder%22%3atrue,%22borderWidth%22%3a%5B0,0,0,0%5D,%22imageOffset%22%3a%5B27,27,27,27%5D,%22setRepat%22%3afalse,%22repeat%22%3a%5B%22repeat%22,%22repeat%22%5D,%22scaleFactor%22:3,%22setRepeat%22%3atrue%7D) property.
It is supported (in the form of prefix variants) by [all major browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp) except you-know-who.

Comment: Unfortunately you-know-who support is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me like you need top,bottom,left,right images (and images for the 4 corners), with a central image you can repeat. Then a little CSS to put them all together correctly. Much like how people used to do rounded corners! The real trick is getting a repeatable central image. That may be made simpler by only sizing your central div in steps which match the size of the central image you end up with.

TBH I don't even know if it's possible to come up with a central mage that won't look like a patch work quilt when repeated.

**EDIT**
I've had a better idea!

If you create images that are effectively masks to "let through" you grassy image. You could use a css sprite technique to size you image, then overlay the side/corner images to get the ragged edge effect. The css sprite would be pulled out of a larger image, large enough to cope with your maximum expected "tile".

Comment: I've thought of this, but it's really complicated, and even then quite irritating to have to constrain all design elements to be multiples of the step size. +1 for a workable proposal though.

Comment: @Joshua - see my edit, I think that'd work really well. But, as you say, it's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your content area in 4 other divs and give the PNG as an image for a different side for each of the divs. The problem is that your content area div will have a solid background and that will show up in the transparent area for your edges.

That being said, you can take a different approach.

Top div
Float Left Edge Div, Content Div, Float Left Edge Div (right edge)
Bottom div

This will be cross browser compatible though a pain to setup.