# Currently available cross-browser nine-patch solution for border-radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nine-patch

I've recently developed for Android and discovered how great 9-patch is. I wondered could it be used in web design, so did [zng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659457/nine-patch-images-for-web-development); the answer is yes.

My question now is, is there anything (a jQuery plugin possibly) out there right now which uses the 9-patch technique to tackle border-radius' lack of cross-browser compatibility, specifically IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a jQuery plugin (as always):

http://code.google.com/p/scale9grid/

Comment: I've recommended this before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975289/how-can-i-make-an-arbitrary-sized-html-element-with-partially-transparent-borders/6975339#6975339. This question isn't a duplicate, even if my answers are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading a good technique called polyfill and shim. [Cross browser polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) are helpful to achieve what you want to do in **one of the smartest way**.

If you go to above link and find **CSS3 Styles** section you will get idea about it.

So the answer to your question is: You can use the example I pointed above to detect the support fro css3. If css3 is supported, you can use border-img property to implement the p-patch technique. Otherwise you can find jQuery alternative OR implement your own like [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) to achieve same.

Please let me know if I can help you further regarding this. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: The only CSS3 border-radius solution there is CSS3PIE. That is not at all what I asked for sorry